# SQLite NullPpointerException Error when trying to call a method

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, nullpointerexception

The aim is to retrieve the car park names from the car park tables columns 'CPNAME' and put those rows of names in another class' arraylist which a spinner will display.

The problem is apparently with my getCpNames() method, specifically on this line:

```
Cursor  c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, KEY_CPNAME, null, null, null,
            null);
```

**The errors I get on LogCat:**

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.example.parkangel.DbHelper.getCpnames(DbHelper.java:93)
at com.example.parkangel.BookTicket.<init>(BookTicket.java:19)
at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2112)
```

**My database class code:**

```
package com.example.parkangel;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
private static DbHelper dbHelper;
private Context ourContext;
private static DbHelper instance;
private static SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "CPDB.db";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "CPTable";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_CPNAME = "cpname";
public static final String KEY_COST = "cost";

    public DbHelper(Context context)
    {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub 
        this.ourContext = context;
    }

    public static DbHelper getInstance(Context context)
    {
        if (instance == null)
        {
            instance = new DbHelper(context);   
        }
        return instance;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
        KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
        KEY_CPNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_COST + " TEXT NOT NULL);");

        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + DATABASE_TABLE + " Values ('1','Learning
                    Resource Center','2');");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + DATABASE_TABLE + " Values ('2','Park and
                    Ride','1');");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + DATABASE_TABLE + " Values ('3','de 
                    Havilland Campus','2');");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + DATABASE_TABLE + " Values ('4','Multi
                    Storey Building','2');");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + DATABASE_TABLE + " Values 
                    ('5','Reception','2');");   
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public synchronized DbHelper open() throws SQLException
    {
        System.out.println ("running open");
        if(ourDatabase == null || !ourDatabase.isOpen());
        this.ourDatabase = getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }   

    public static String[] getCpnames()
    {
        String[] columns = new String[] {KEY_ID, KEY_CPNAME, KEY_COST};
        Cursor  c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, KEY_CPNAME,
                    null, null, null, null);
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        if (c != null)
        {
            c.moveToFirst();
            do
            {
                list.add(c.getString(0));
            }           
            while (c.moveToNext());
        }
        if (ourDatabase == null) System.out.println ("is null");

        return list.toArray(new String[]{});
    }   
}
```

**This is the class and arraylist I am calling getCpnames() into:**

```
package com.example.parkangel;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class BookTicket extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

Spinner spinner, spinner2;
DbHelper dbhelper = DbHelper.getInstance(this);
String[] carParks = DbHelper.getCpnames();
```

I am beginner, so apologies for any amateur mistakes. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never called DbHelper.open();

BTW, I also see a potential problem here

```
public synchronized DbHelper open() throws SQLException
{
    System.out.println ("running open");
    if(ourDatabase == null || !ourDatabase.isOpen());
    this.ourDatabase = getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}
```

especially on this line 
        if(ourDatabase == null || !ourDatabase.isOpen());

The semicolon ";" at the end of line makes the if statement ineffective

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Do I call DbHelper.open(); under onCreate() of my BookTicket class? When I tried this it said the method had to be changed to static, I followed through with it however within that method it said this.ourDatabase = getWritableDatabase(); cannot make a reference from a static to a non-static method.

Comment: First of all make sure you understand what static means. You can imagine that static members (functions and attributes) belong to class. Non-static members belong to the instance of the class (object). When you call a static method, it can not reference non-static member. How can class know, which instance you mean?

Comment: When you change the method to static then 
    this.ourDatabase = getWritableDatabase();
generates an error, because you use "this". It means "this instance". Remove it.

Comment: Ok there's been progression but now I get an error saying getDatabaseLocked(). I have checked where else my code is writing into the car park database but I cant figure out what is :@

Answer (score 0):

The most likely explanation is that `ourDatabase` is null. You failed to call `DBHelper.open()` to set it.

Comment: Yep, I just don't know how to fix that. Tried a lot of different answers on stack but to no avail...